# Prevent duplicates sql server

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates

Ok, in this query I'm extracting information from 5 tables, the table Company, Programmer, Tester, Manager and the table Contract. I will extract the Programmers', testers', and Managers' Names and Telephone Numbers, as well as the Company they work on, and this company is responsible for managing this program as a request by x person doesn't matter.

Problem is with the code below, a certain information will come out as many times as there is other information, like a programmer's Name and Tel Number will come out as many times as there are Managers and Testers on the company.

I tried with left outer join and it would give me even more results, so how can I fix this so next time a result won't be duplicated but say NULL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT pg.name,
                pg.Tel_Nr,
                Mgr.name,
                Mgr.Tel_Nr,
                Ts.Name,
                Ts.Tel_Nr,
                Pg.Name,
                con.program_name
FROM Company AS Cm
INNER JOIN Programmer AS Pg ON Pg.company = Cm.name
INNER JOIN Manager AS Mg ON Mg.company = Cm.name
INNER JOIN Tester AS Ts ON Ts.company = Cm.name
INNER JOIN Contract AS Con ON Con.program_name = 'My Program'
AND Cm.name = Con.Company
```

Comment: due to which tables you are getting problem.. manager & tester ?

Comment: Say there are 2 managers, a programmer and a tester. my results will be first row:
pg1,pg1_tel,mgr1,mgr1_tel,ts1,ts1.tel, cmp.name

I need it that on the second row pg1, pg1.tel be NULL since they have been found before, the same with ts1, ts1.tel
then it will be second row: pg1,pg1_tel,mgr2,mgr2_tel,ts1,ts1.tel, cmp.name

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would make more sense to produce a list of contact details with perhaps a job description.  Something like this:

```
WITH Cte as (select Cm.name from 
      Contract as Con join Company as Cm on  Cm.name = Con.Company
     where Con.program_name = 'My Program')
SELECT pg.name,  pg.Tel_Nr, 'Programmer' as JobTitle
FROM  Cte   INNER JOIN
    Programmer as Pg  on Pg.company = Cte.name 
UNION ALL
SELECT Mgr.name,  Mgr.Tel_Nr,'Manager' as JobTitle
FROM  Cte   INNER JOIN
     Manager as Mg on Mg.company= Cte.name 
UNION ALL
SELECT Ts.Name,  Ts.Tel_Nr, 'Tester' as JobTitle
FROM  Cte   INNER JOIN
    Tester as Ts on Ts.company = Cte.name
```

This solution deploys a Common Table Expression (labelled `Cte`) to avoid querying thr `Company` and `Contract` tables multiple times.  [Find out more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that did the job, but it was a little bit different from what I had done. Mind a question, what is Cte?

Comment: It's a common table expression: a way of re-using one sub-query in several different places in our main query.